# Confused about how to properly add a white border to my numpy imagearray with numpy.pad

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I've used openCV2 to load a grayscale image, which I then converted to a numpy.array. Now I want to pad that array with a 'frame' around the image. However, I'm having some trouble dissecting what the numpy manual wants me to do exactly. I tried googling and searching for padding examples, none came up that were relevant for my case.

My current code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('Lena.png', )
imgArray = np.array((img))
imgArray = np.pad(imgArray, pad_width=1,mode='constant' ,constant_values=0)
cv2.imshow('Padded', imgArray)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('Lena.png', 0)
img = np.pad(img, pad_width=4, mode='constant', constant_values=0)
cv2.imshow('Padded', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread) of `cv2.imread`:

> `cv2.imread(filename[, flags]) → retval`

Parameters:

- filename – Name of file to be loaded.
- flags:

**Flags** specifying the color type of a loaded image:

CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH - If set, return 16-bit/32-bit image when the input has the corresponding depth, otherwise convert it to 8-bit.

CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR - If set, always convert image to the color one

CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE - If set, always convert image to the grayscale one

>0 Return a 3-channel color image.
Note In the current implementation the alpha channel, if any, is stripped from the output image. Use negative value if you need the alpha channel.

**=0** Return a **grayscale** image.

<0 Return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel).

**With the above code we got the following result:**

[image]

Comment: What does the second imread parameter '0' do?

Also it doesn't seem to work. I get the following error when trying this method
TypeError: mat data type = 17 is not supported

Comment: @MikkelGHansen Please check the path to the file, that will be the cause of error msg, I think.

Comment: @MikkelGHansen See result above

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Everytime I've used cv2.imread I've simply put the second parameter as the image reference up until now. :P 

The suggested code change indeed added a border to my image. Although i find it very odd that my original image is in the center, when I expected there to be only blackness atm. Pic for reference: http://prntscr.com/lfij4v

The reason for the manipulated image to be in the corner, I presume is due to my for loop iterating from 0, to image.shape 
Pic for code ref: http://prntscr.com/lfikn0

Comment: @MikkelGHansen I'm happy about your success, however for further thoughts, I should see more from your relevant code.

Comment: On second thought. I got the padding working, which was the center of this question so I'll close down this question as 'answered' before we stray too much off topic. Thanks alot for the assistance! We can continue at my next post, which handles the problem with my image
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53193497/getting-a-incorrect-picture-output-when-running-my-self-made-rotation-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Check out the openCV2 documentation here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html

My best guess is to use `constant= cv2.copyMakeBorder(img,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=BLUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I see you already have an answer, I wanted to show the general case where you want to pad with something other than black or white, i.e. you want to add a coloured border. I couldn't get any of the methods suggested in the other answers to do that, so...

Say you have `lena.png` as follows:

[image]

Then you can do:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps                                                                                                
import numpy as np    

# Load the image - you could just as well use OpenCV `imread()`
img = Image.open('lena.png')   

# Pad 20px to all sides with magenta
padded = ImageOps.expand(img, border=20, fill=(255,0,255)) 

# Save to disk
padded.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

Before anyone decides to downvote because the OP asked how to add *white* borders, please note you can just as easily add white with this method if you use:

```
padded = ImageOps.expand(img, border=20, fill=(255,255,255))
```

---

If you are using `numpy` arrays to manipulate your images, you can convert from `numpy` array to PIL `Image` with:

```
pil_image = Image.fromarray(numpy_array)
```

and the other way with:

```
numpy_array = np.array(pil_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

And another option using np.pad:

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349410/how-to-pad-with-zeros-a-tensor-along-some-axis-python), you need to supply the axis you want to np.pad. Simply using:

```
    imgArray = np.pad(imgArray, pad_width=1, mode='constant', constant_values=0)
```

adds only values to the third axis (i.e. the RGB channel), so that you cannot plot the image any more.

As described in the referenced question, you would need to use the following arguments to you code:

```
   imgArray = np.pad(imgArray, pad_width=((1,1), (1,1), (0,0)), mode='constant', constant_values=0)
```

Also see the np.pad [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

> Number of values padded to the edges of each axis. ((before_1, after_1), … (before_N, after_N)) unique pad widths for each axis. ((before, after),) yields same before and after pad for each axis. (pad,) or int is a shortcut for before = after = pad width for all axes.

This means the first entry of tuple pads the first axis (in case of an image the upper and lower border) and the second tuple pads the second axis (the left and right borders) with one "0".

You do not want to pad the last dimension, as this is the dimension storing the RGB information.

And as you stated in your question that you want a white border: constant_values should be set to 255 or 1, depending on the range of your image. Using 0 results in a black border.

Comment: The extra pad_width arguments didn't seem to work, since I assume the 3 arguments represents 3 color channels, and my grayscale image only got 1. I'll keep it in mind when trying with colored images, thanks :D

Comment: Given that the input only adds a single pixel to each dimension it's possible that they are not visible. I actually just wanted to explain why pad=1 doesn't work, as it also pads the last axis. If you have gray scale images of shape=[x,y,1], this would still affect the color channel. If the image gray scale image is only 2 dimensional, then it shouldn't matter actually.

Comment: Ah, I see! Tried inputting only two parameters instead of 3 and got it working. I'll be careful about padding all axes in the future, thank you! :D However, now I've run into the same issue I posted on Geeocode's answer above :(