# How to pad a specific dimension of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to create a class that Right Pads a Numpy array to have the shape (257, 87). Currently the array has shape (257, 24), so I only need to pad the 2nd dim. I've tried a few iterations of the below class, but it always pads both dimensions.

```
class Padder:
  def __init__(self, mode="constant"):
    self.mode = mode

  def right_pad(self, array):
    num_missing_items = 87 - array.shape[1]
    padded_array = np.pad(array,
                          (num_missing_items, 0),
                          mode=self.mode)
    return padded_array
```

This results in shape (320, 87).

I also tried indexing the input array

```
class Padder:
  def __init__(self, mode="constant"):
    self.mode = mode

  def right_pad(self, array):
    num_missing_items = 87 - array.shape[1]
    padded_array = np.pad(array[1],
                          (num_missing_items, 0),
                          mode=self.mode)
    return padded_array
```

But this only returns the padded 2nd dim, nothing in the first dim, shape = (87,). So I tried to create a new array with the first dim as the original array's 1st dim, and 2nd dim as the padded 2nd dim.

```
class Padder:
  def __init__(self, mode="constant"):
    self.mode = mode

  def right_pad(self, array):
    num_missing_items = 87 - array.shape[1]
    padded_array = np.array([array[0], np.pad(array[1],
                          (num_missing_items, 0),
                          mode=self.mode)])
    return padded_array
```

But this returns an array of shape (2,)

How can I use padding to get my array to shape (257, 870)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pad with zeros a tensor along some axis (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349410/how-to-pad-with-zeros-a-tensor-along-some-axis-python)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the docs for the pad_width parameter for np.pad:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html

You can pass it a sequence of (before, after) tuples. In your case, the (before, after) for the first dimension needs to be (0, 0), and you can choose yourself for the second. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)
padded = np.pad(arr, ((0, 0), (2, 3)))
```

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  3,  4,  5,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  7,  8,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  9, 10, 11,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are obvious duplicates of questions with
accepted answers, rather flag them or vote to close them to avoid duplicate
content.

Comment: Feel free to remove my post, I wasnt aware there was a duplicate

Comment: @ljmc, your posting times overlapped.  Duplicates only count when they actually close the question, not when they are suggested via comments.  And this link to the official documentation is useful, may be even more so than a duplicate with multiple answers.